# Program stops working and an error message is displayed when i run it

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

This error message is shown in every software.

> it has stop working check online solution and close the program

There is no error in code but when I run this program I got this error and I found that most of the program where user input is required it stops working. I have used code blocks, C free, dev C++

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
struct student
{
    int roll;
    char name[10];
} stu1 = {100, "ram"};

main()
{
    struct student stu2;
    printf("2nd student name is:  %s \n",stu1.name);
    printf("second student roll no:  %s \n ",stu1.roll);
    printf("enter second student data  ");
    scanf("%d", &stu2.roll);
    printf("enter second student name  ");
    scanf("%s",&stu2.name);
    printf("2nd student name is:  %s \n",stu2.name);
    printf("second student roll no:  %s \n ",stu2.roll);

    getch();
}
```

Image with error message: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZsAU.png

Comment: Did you even check the code after writing? The orders are all messed up

Comment: Did you even check the question after writing?

Comment: Are you asking us to do your homework?

Comment: no i just wanted to know that if there is no error in code then why this msg is dislplaying every time "it has stop working  check online solution and close the program"

Comment: You don't need `&` with `scanf()` while reading as string with `%s`

Comment: To help people answer your question, you'll need to be more specific about the error.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the exact errors you get from your [mcve] (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then **use the debugger**  `gdb`. BTW `conio.h` is not standard

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct student
{
    int roll;
    char name[10];
}stu1 = {100, "ram"};



int main()
{
    struct student stu2;
    printf("2nd student name is:  %s \n",stu1.name);
    printf("second student roll no:  %d \n ",stu1.roll); // line 1
    printf("enter second student data  ");
    scanf("%d", &stu2.roll);
    printf("enter second student name  ");
    scanf("%s",stu2.name); // line 2
    printf("2nd student name is:  %s \n",stu2.name);
    printf("second student roll no:  %d \n ",stu2.roll); // line 3

    return 0;
}
```

I have corrected the code like this. Lines 1, 2 and 3 was the problem I think. While changing those lines as shown above code no longer runs to segmentation fault.

NB : Don't use `scanf` for user input. If you use `scanf` at all, always check its return value. `scanf` `%s` is a bug: It can't prevent buffer overflows from longer input.

Answer (score 0):

This could be another approach:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

typedef struct
{
    int roll;
    char *name;
} studentT;

int main()
{
    studentT stu1, stu2;

    stu1.roll = 100;
    stu1.name = "ram";

    printf("2nd student name is:  %s \n",stu1.name);
    printf("second student roll no:  %d \n ",stu1.roll);

    printf("enter second student data  ");
    scanf("%d", &stu2.roll);
    printf("enter second student name  ");
    scanf("%s",&stu2.name);

    printf("2nd student name is:  %s \n",stu2.name);
    printf("second student roll no:  %d \n ",stu2.roll);

    getch();
}
```